# Add value in a field for a given condition in specific column of file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, text

I need prefix digit `9` to the second column of file when the value of second column begins with `10` and length of second column is `8`
Example

`file.txt`

```
T01|10017516|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH   
T01|10905704|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH           
T01|550007656|02|ABCD|1203|EFGH     
T01|550007657|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH      
T01|10190570|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH                             
T01|950007659|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH           
T01|950007657|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH           
T01|10473696|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|850007651|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH
```

The result should be:

```
T01|910017516|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|910905704|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|550007656|02|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|550007657|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|910190570|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|950007659|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|950007657|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH   
T01|910473696|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH  
T01|850007651|01|ABCD|1203|EFGH
```

Comment: Hello, the rule is that second field begin with 10 and its length is 8, if two conditions are met add digit 9, I hep you please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `perl` and GNU `sed`

```
perl -pe 's/^[^|]*\|\K(10\d{6}\|)/9$1/' file.txt

sed -r 's/^([^|]*\|)(10[0-9]{6}\|)/\19\2/' file.txt
```

In either case, you can add `-i.bkp` to change the file inplace and copy original file to `file.txt.bkp` or just `-i` if backup is not required

**Edit:**

Thanks @drg for pointing out error in perl one-liner..`^.*?\|` would not ensure matching 2nd column.. for example, `ab|asd|10017516|asd` would be erroneously changed

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (and I'm  hoping should not be in need of explanation)

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '$2 ~ /^10/ && length($2) == 8{$2="9"$2}; {print}' file.txt
```